# How to implement Column level security in Palantir foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-security

I am trying to find a way to implement column level security using restricted views and policies.

I want to hide and show columns based on rules just like row level security.

How we do that ?

Implemented row level security but didn't saw anything which will be applied to columns as well. There is deprecated feature 'mark as policy column' we can't use that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the Ontology if your objects are stored in Object Storage V2: you can use multiple dataset backed objects by going into

`Object type > Properties > Edit property mapping > Add a datasource`

Your various datasources can have different permissions and users will only see the fields coming from the datasets they have access to.